# React-native-video extremely slow and possible workaround

Tags: react-native, local-storage, video-streaming, asyncstorage, react-native-video

*What am I doing?*

A react-native-video component is loaded into the screen with a source uri from my nodejs backend.

*What is the problem?* (Only tried on android)

My backend is working fine and the video is loaded, but **extremely slow**. I checked on the backend that the video component is **requesting a byte-range of 1MB every ~1s**. On the other hand, if I request the video ranges with axios, it takes a couple of ms to request multiple byte-ranges.
When using a video stored locally on the android device, the loading time is almost instantaneous.
I tried the default android player as well as exoplayer with no difference in loading times.
I am trying all this with only one Video component and when I comment it the app runs smoothly

*Possible solution:*

I don't want to load the data directly from the Video component and I am trying now to download the byte-ranges and store them locally. Later I plan to load these byte-ranges into the Video component.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
...
await AsyncStorage.setItem(video_name, JSON.stringify(byte_range_data_from_backend))
```

This works fine and I can read the byte_range_data_from_backend later with:

```
const data_from_item = await AsyncStorage.getItem(video_name)
```

*What is my question?*

How can I get these video_ranges uris to pass them to the Video component?
I think I need to create some kind of file and update the file content every time I receive a new byte-range. Meanwhile, I would like the video to be played using the already downloaded byte-ranges.

Is this possible or is not a good approach? **What would be a possible way to load videos fast?** It would be nice to download some byte-ranges before even trying to play the video, so that the waiting time for the user is minimal.